# How to implement server side web push notification in my blazor app just like facebook type notification

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am using **Syncfusin** toast notification in my project.

But I want to implement server side notification in my application just like Facebook notification.

I want To my application notified when any entry occurred in my Azur SQL database table .

I want to send multiple user notification and single user notification .

Please help me how can I achieved this.

Blazor server side

Database Azur SQL server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notification Implementation In blazor Server Side Web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233039/notification-implementation-in-blazor-server-side-web-application)

Comment: I think you already asked a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65233039/notification-implementation-in-blazor-server-side-web-application Please decide which one to have open...