# Notification Implementation In blazor Server Side Web application

Tags: blazor-server-side

How can I achieved notification in my Blazor Server Side Web application using Azur SQL server. Whenever Database table new entry occurred I want to show notification in my web page to all users or particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but requires "custom" feature implementation. It's not a huge task you need only a WebSocket channel to push messages. Since you have Server side Blazor it is already doing it with SignalR Hubs (extra functionality over WebSocket).

Here is some [MS docs for Blazor + SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&pivots=server) (some of the code will already in your app since it's Sever side Blazor).

```
hubConnection.On<string>("TableUpdate", (tableName) =>
{
    //Prompt some Alert, or Notifications here...
    StateHasChanged();
});
```

Once you set up your Hub connection you can push status updates to the clients (to all `Clients.All.SendAsync()` or targeting some clients `Clients.User(userId)`).  You can use this [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Majorsoft.Blazor.Components.Notifications) also [docs](https://github.com/majorimi/blazor-components/blob/master/.github/docs/Notifications.md) and [demo](https://blazorextensions.z6.web.core.windows.net/notifications) available. To prompt one of the following notifications:

- Alerts
- Toast messages
- HTML5 notification